# Drupal Views Datasource and Flag Links

Tags: views, flags, 8

I want to use Views Datasource module to output JSON, i then want to construct the JSON output using REACT JS or alike. I am currently stuck on how to output the Flag Link, it just comes back with an OPS field. Ideally i want this as a plain link so I can trigger it through jquery/ajax.

[image: Views Field]

[image: Ops Field]

UPDATE: as requested using the php field i managed to get the output i was after which is something like:
[image: plain text output]

Comment: I might have a possible alternative for you to consider. But can you first enhance your question to better explain what I should see (or not see) in the JSON sample in your (last) picture. Maybe something like "this is what I get, but this is what I would like to get"?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens done

Comment: OK, that helps already quite a bit to better understand. But is your new result now something like the first JSON picture, in which the lines in your last picture are inserted somewhere? And also: did you actually "manage" to do so using Views PHP (as in your answer)? Last question: do you insist in using "Views datasource" (and views PHP), or are you open to an alternative solution that does not require those 2 modules? Just to make sure my possible answer might fit "also", ok?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens, my new result is in the right format i.e. showing me the path to the flag and with token. yes i did manage to do it with Views PHP and no i don;t insist on using View data source and Views PHP (would much rather avoid using Views PHP), but Viewsdata source makes it very easy.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I couldn't get the perfect solution to this so I had to use Views PHP. Remember to add a hidden field for the nid of the node

```
<?php
$link = flag_create_link('MyFlagMachineName', $row->nid);
preg_match_all('/<a[^>]+href=([\'"])(.+?)\1[^>]*>/i', $link, $result);
if (!empty($result)) {
  echo $result[2][0];
}
?>
```